# Power Automate - Popup window instance

Tags: rpa, power-automate-desktop

I have one application here, where I have a web browser (instance `NewBrowser`), I input some information and then the browser is updated, after it updated, I click a button and a new window is poped up.

Here is where I'm struggling, because I need to work on the new browser that popped out and I do not know how to refer to it

Any help?